# iOS - Disable row select while method is processing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Ok, this is my first question so be gentle!

I have a `UITableView` in iOS (we are developing using Xamarin c#) where selecting a row will deserialise a view coming from the server before displaying it. This works fine on my iPad mini Retina with no problems and the same on the simulator. However, users with iPad 3 or below have a huge delay waiting for the deserialiser to finish its job. We have optimised it the best that we can but we still have a delay.

This delay allows users to tap the row multiple times (thinking it is not doing anything) which causes the processing to happen multiple times and then multiple instances of the deserialised view to appear on the stack which causes a navigation error and the app to crash when trying to navigate back down the stack.

My question is, is there a way to stop row click events being processed for that particular row after the first press until we have navigated back to that controller? I have tried using the WillSelectRow and a class variable bool (quick example below)

```
bool isProcessing = false;
    public override NSIndexPath WillSelectRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if(!isProcessing)
            return indexPath;
        return null;
    }

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        isProcessing = true;            

        var data = GetDataAt(indexPath);

        ProcessRowSelection(tableView, indexPath, data);

        isProcessing = false;

    }
```

Problem is, when i have tried this approach, it doesn't stop the second tap from being registered as it fires the entire execution for the first tap before starting the second so essentially, the boolean never traps it.

Any ideas would be kindly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using a class variable sounds like a good option in this case.

In the method that's called upon selecting the cell, you can use a conditional to specify whether or not to deserialize the view.  If `isProcessing` == `NO`, set `isProcessing` to `YES` and deserialize the view; otherwise, don't deserialize the view. Then once the view is done deserializing, set `isProcessing` to `NO`.

Another good option would be to set the cell or even the entire table's `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO` then re-enable interaction once the view is done deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to move that logic to the `rowSelected` method:

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    if(!isProcessing)
    {
        isProcessing = true;            
        var data = GetDataAt(indexPath);
        ProcessRowSelection(tableView, indexPath, data);
    }
    else
    {
        isProcessing = false;
    }
}
```